# Accessing php variable from within function scope

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code in a codeigniter controller that's the beginnings of a pagination/sorting feature for a table in the view.  I'm passing `order_by` as a query parameter and then this is part of the controller action:

```
if ($order_by)
{
  function compare_items ($a, $b){
    return $b['value'][$order_by] <=> $a['value'][$order_by];
  };
  usort($data['items'], 'compare_items');
}
```

The problem is...I keep getting the error `Undefined variable: order_by`.

Since I'm checking that `$order_by` exists in the if statement, why am I getting this error? Even putting `var_dump()` inside the if statement returns a string that matches whatever I put in the query param. And hardcoding a value (`return $b['value']['<test_param>'] <=> $a['value']['<test_param>'];`) works just fine, even when if leave the if statement as is.

Is there some php scope behavior I'm not aware of that's causing this error? I'm really a javascript/React dev, and I'm hoping I'm just missing something simple in php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use "use" for external variables

```
if ($order_by)
{
    usort($data['items'], function ($a, $b) use ($order_by) {
        return $b['value'][$order_by] <=> $a['value'][$order_by];
    });
}
```